# Documenting possible values for Map in Swagger

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a JAX-RS method which takes a Map to facilitate a partial update.

```
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/{id}/edit")
   public Response edit(HashMap<String, Object> data)
```

I can't use Patch, long story. 
I need to document what parameters are possible for client to send up so they can see them in swagger UI. One way to do this is to use `@ApiImplicitParam`

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "payload", value = "payload", required = true, dataType = "com.me.PartialUpdatePerson", paramType = "body"),
})
```

This is a nice work around.  PartialUpdatePerson is a class which contains the various parameters allowed to be sent up.

The problem is in the swagger UI, it still shows me the body with the map.  Sample value is:

```
{
  "additionalProp1": {},
  "additionalProp2": {},
  "additionalProp3": {}
}
```

as well as the payload.

Is there anyway, I can tell swagger, not to show this?  i.e. to ignore the HashMap data from a doc perspective?  I am not using Spring so @ApiIgnore is not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public Response edit(@ApiParam(hidden = true) HashMap<String, Object> data)
```